# Delayed Job - Find by object id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, delayed-job

I have using Rails + DelayedJob Mongoid. I have this model:

```
class User
  def run
    ...
  end
end
```

I create new `Dejayed::Job` object:

```
user = Use.create
user.delay.run
```

How I can I do something like this?

```
Delajed::Job.where(object_id: user.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @aelor answer, finally I had to add field `object_id` to Job class:

```
# config/initializers/dejayed_job.rb

module Delayed
  module Backend
    module Mongoid
      class Job
        include ::Mongoid::Document
        field :object_id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then it works ok:

```
user = Use.create
user.delay(object_id: user.id).run

Delayed::Job.where(object_id: 5).first
=> #<Delayed::Backend::Mongoid::Job _id: 551a5116726a750e08000000
```

Comment: Tried your solution on a non Mongoid delayed job and it seems to dislike the field :). I did find a good tutorial on how to wrap delayed jobs and provide similar and even better customizations: https://www.sitepoint.com/delayed-jobs-best-practices/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work in your case.

If you have the delayed_job object id, you can simply find it like normal activerecord objects.

```
# find a job by id
job = Delayed::Job.find(params[:id])
```

Now when you dont have the id. Then add something unique during the creation of the job itself

in **users_controller.rb**

```
user = User.create
```

in **user.rb**

```
def delayed_run
  my_job = MyJob.new('xyz')
  job = Delayed::Job.enqueue(run, 0, 1.hour.from_now)
  job.user_id = self.id
end
```

So after this, you can find your delayed job object from the unique user_id

```
Delayed::Job.where(user_id: 5)
```

Comment: This give me this error: undefined method `user_id=' for #<Delayed::Backend::Mongoid::Job:0x000000064d8860>. I had to Monkey patch Job class. Thanks for the idea.